# What is the correct term for ->,->* and .* operators?

Tags: c++, operators, naming, operator-arrow-star

Wikipedia refers to them as:

> -> Member b of object pointed to by a
>   ->* Member pointed to by b of object pointed to by a
>   .* Member pointed to by b of object a

But I need to refer to them without using "a" and "b". Do they have any names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard has calls `->*` and `.*` "pointer-to-member operators" (5.5). The former expects the first operand to be of pointer type, the second of class type.

Similarly, `->` and `.` are called "class member access" (5.2.5), or "dot" and "arrow".

Answer (score 2):

If you're discussing them in conversation, I us the terms::

```
->   "Arrow"  eg. "B-arrow-A"
->*  "Arrow-star"  eg.  "B-arrow-star-A" 
.*   "Dot-star"    eg.  "B-dot-star-A"
```

When writing about them, I prefer the terms others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is

- member access operator (–>)
- pointer-dereference operator (*)
- Pointer-to-member selection (.*) [according to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx), at least]